# Difference between anonymous class and normal derived class when faced with Gson?

Tags: java, gson

When I use the Gson library, I found anonymous class and normal derived class led to different output using `gson.toJson()`.Here is the code(Just to demonstrate, ignore the grammar):

The derived class:

```
class StringWrap {
    private String str = "qwerty";
}

Object derived = new StringWrap();
```

The anonymous class:

```
Object anonymous = new Object(){
        private String str="qwerty";
    };
```

As it turned out, `new Gson().toJson(derived)` return `{"str":"qwerty"}`, but `new Gson().toJson(anonymous)` returns `null`.

Is there something different between the anonymous class and the derived class? Or is it something concerning Gson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson doesn't support anonymous classes.
I found this in the gson user guide: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

> Fields corresponding to the outer classes in inner classes, anonymous classes, and local classes are ignored and not included in serialization or deserialization

Comment: @obfish anonymous classes are expressions where as local classes are declarations.  Anonymous classes allow you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They are also nameless.